# Find if union of discrete intervals with holes covers the whole interval space

Tags: intervals, subsequences

There is a whole space interval `[0,128]`

And several discrete sequences like:

`[0, 1, 4, 5, 32, 33, 36, 37, 64, 65, 68, 69, 96, 97, 100, 101]`

`[32, 33, 36, 37, 48, 49, 52, 53, 96, 97, 100, 101, 112, 113, 116, 117]`

`[12, 13, 28, 29, 44, 45, 60, 61, 76, 77, 92, 93, 108, 109, 124, 125]`

They look like this

[image]

and can be described by (start element, last element, step between elements in subgroup, step between subgroups, number of subgroups).

Literally, every sequence created this way:

1. Take start sequence of numbers `[n,m]` (any numbers count)
2. For every number make `[n * 2,(n * 2) + step,(m * 2),(m * 2) + step]`
3. Do this recursively upto to wished bound

Example: `[0,2]` -> `[0,1,4,5]` -> `[0,1,2,3,8,9,10,11]` and so on, with `step = 1`

Note: step is fixed for each sequence.

My task is to find out if set of such sequences covers every number from interval [0,128]

Is it possible to perform this without allocating every number from [0,128] ?
Interval combination is also not effective due to elements growth. Maybe there is some math field that similar to this?

Comment: Your example sequences contain many elements, but in the way you describe them each of them seem to have only 4 elements. Which one is it?

Comment: @Steven, improved description to it be more clear

Comment: What's wrong with allocating every number from [0,128]?  That will be super-fast, and probably far more efficient of your time than trying to find a complex algorithm.  Have you tried implementing the obvious solution and benchmarking how long it takes?

Comment: @D.W. problem starts when this space and sequences grow up. Every step sequences doubles and grows as power of two - exponentially